# how i can find a specific value from the table using groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\dataset\covid.csv')
df.head(50)
```

I want to find the total_cases values for all the countries in the date '2021-02-09' using the `groupby` function. Here is the table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `grouby` function is not necessary here, as you can use a function built into the `pandas` module you are using, [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.loc[df['date'] == '2021-02-09', 'total_cases']
```